# Excel Datevalue issue

Tags: excel, date

I have some dates in column A in the form "Sep 01 2019" (etc). The Excel format I have selected on the dates is "General". The `IsText` function confirms that they are all text.

When I then go to use `DateValue` on them I get `#Value`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `DateValue` cannot recognize this format. `01 Sep 2019` or `01-Sep-2019` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,2)&" "&LEFT(A1,3)&" "&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

or to get a date:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3)),MID(A1,5,2))
```

The Datevalue formula can probably be a bit different depending on your locale.

Another option for you could be to select that column of text looking like dates and:

- Data > Text to Columns
- Fixed width > Next
- Remove breaks > Next
- Column data format > "MDY"
- Stick with the column they are in already > Confirm

They should be converted to legitimate date values now.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing spaces by `-` `=datevalue(substitute(yourcell," ","-"))`